# Thought process for this trigonometric proof

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

**To prove**: If $\sin x +  \sin y = 2\sin(x+y)$ with $(x+y)\neq 0$ ,prove that $\tan (x/2) \tan (y/2) = 1/3$.

**My attempt**: I have not been able to figure out how to attempt this proof problem correctly. I had tried to simplify the given equation but it was of no use. I had also tried to simplify the L.H.S but all i got was some weird expression.

**My problem**: I have been facing a lot of problem proving trigonometric results like these. Most of the times i cannot figure out where to start from and how to start. Should i take the L.H.S of the required result and show that it is equal to the R.H.S by simplifying or vice-versa or should i modify the given equation to obtain the required result. How can i figure out how to proceed and what should be my thought process for tackling proof problems like these.

Comment: Actually, that's not true for $x=y=\pi$, you need the assumption $x+y\neq 2\,k\,\pi$. Then, you need a working knowledge of basic trigonometric identities (addition theorems, double angle formula,...), and lots of experience, gained through exercise. The latter meaning doing or trying, not watching others doing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

At first what to be proved,
$\tan{\dfrac{x}{2}}\tan{\dfrac{y}{2}}=1/3 \Rightarrow 2\sin{\dfrac{x}{2}}\sin{\dfrac{y}{2}}=\dfrac{2\cos{\dfrac{x}{2}} \cos{\dfrac{y}{2}}}{3}$

$\Rightarrow\cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}- \cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}=\dfrac{\cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}+\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}}{3} \Rightarrow \cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}=2\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}.$

Now the given side,
$\sin{x}+\sin{y}=4\sin{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}} \Rightarrow 2\sin{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}=4\sin{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}} \Rightarrow \cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}=2\cos{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}.$

Hence proved.

Comment: L.H.S and R.H.S stand for left hand side and right hand side respectively and are applicable for a particular equation. You cannot say that a particular equation is L.H.S or R.H.S.

Comment: Where have you used the (necessary!) restriction on $x+y$?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes I have used the necessary resitriction, i.e. $$x+y\neq 0$$

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty, *Where* have you used it?

Comment: Since, $x+y\neq 0, \therefore,$ in the last step I could divide, $\sin{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\neq 0$.

Comment: @ChandramauliChakraborty, as Professor Vector pointed out in comments, $\pi+\pi\not=0$, but you cannot divide by $\sin{\pi+\pi\over2}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra, I agree with you, but here the case is that $$\sin{0}=\sin{n\pi}$$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I hope that it is clear.

Comment: So for any case $$x+y\neq n\pi$$.

Comment: You are missing the point, which is that the OP's restriction, that $x+y\not=0$, is not sufficient.  What's actually required for your proof to work is that $\sin{x+y\over2}\not=0$, which is to say, $x+y\not=2n\pi$ for *any* $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yeah, that should be the require condition,thank you for this useful correction.